# Function-style casting a pointer

Tags: c++

Chapter 4.11.3 of the book C++ Primer says the following:

> In early versions of C++, an explicit cast took one of the following two forms:

```
type (expr); // function-style cast notation
(type) expr; // C-language-style cast notation
```

I get that C-style casting a pointer works like this:

```
int*  ip = nullptr;
void* vp = (void*) ip;
```

However, I can't find how to do this with a function-style cast. The code below does not work, and I can see why. How can I get this to work?

```
int*  ip = nullptr;
void* vp = void*(ip);
```

Comment: It's not really possible. And in C++ using a C-style cast should generally be seen as a red flag that you're doing something wrong. I really recommend using only the standard C++ cast operators (e.g. `static_cast` etc.).

Comment: Functional cast requires the type name to be a single word, without spaces or punctuation symbols.

Comment: `using void_p = void*; void_p(ip)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this way:

```
using voidPointer = void*;

int*  ip = nullptr;
void* vp = voidPointer(ip);
```

This works because it makes the type a single word. Alternatively, this works too:

```
typedef void* voidPointer;
```

Comment: ... Of course, casting any data-pointer to `void*` is rarely a good idea. Specifically only if implicit conversion does not work.

Comment: Given that `using` (C++11) wasn't there in the "early" versions of C++, it might make more sense to use `typedef` here.

Comment: @P.P `using` does everything that `typedef` does and more. There really is *no* reason to ever use `typedef` in new / modern code - `typedef` needs to just silently go away and die, it is obsolete.

Comment: @JesperJuhl My comment is in the context of the question, which was about "early versions of C++" where `using` didn't exist. Not for advocating `typedef`.

Comment: @Jeffrey Just wondering what does void* mean?? Usually void means the function does not return anything, so does void* mean nullptr??